# Fastest and light way(Sqlite or core data or plist or csv or flat file)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a simple problem to solve but want to know which is better pattern to use and understand the reason for the choice. 
Problem :
I want to create a utility which developers can use to check whether the feature should be enabled/disabled depending on the server package version.

eg : server package versions like 10.234, 11.1 etc and client versions 9.3,10.2 etc

Validation on client to see min version on server package for feature to be enabled/disabled.
example data would be like "search lookup feature >= 10.234". And sometimes complex situation need to even check client version whether the feature should be supported.

edit:
Note: Application is very huge and memory is full for most of the time. (thousands of records of organisation data.) So memory is bottle neck.

Just it even flashed to mind to used macro as to do all comparisons and returning value.

I think Plist would be heavy as all the objects would be in NSDictionary and even to access one object, I'll be holding all data.

I want to reduce memory overhead and comparisons too.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if any of the answers satisfy your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Light data, Use **NSUserDefaults** or **PList**. SQLite and Core Data is overkilled.

**Updated Answer for Updated Question**:-

For server package versions/your app version or other light weight data, you can always use **NSUserDefaults** or **PList**.

For records of organisation data, you might want to consider **Core Data**.

Yes, you can use 2 different types of persistent storage inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is never going to change, or grow you better use `NSUserDefaults`, `plist` or `csv` file. If you think that user should have the ability to change or add new entries to this data file you better go ahead with `CoreData`

Comment: data will not change, plist, csv, NSUserDefaults (again plist) would want to parse and all would be in memory always :(

Answer (score 0):

Plists, csv, and flat files have low overhead for small to medimum amounts of data (and for data where you use all or nearly all) of it.

Systems that only use some of the data on any given run AND have large amounts of data AND have the data structured so SELECT can use an index can be faster (lots and lots faster) with a database (SQLite, or CoreData with the SQL Persistant store).

As a gut feel I expect your problem could be handled well by SQL, but only if you are talking about 1000s of configurations not 10s or even 100s...but you would be better served by benchmarks then my guesses.  Go code :-)

Comment: Ya coding and tracking is going on parallel. Want to know which design pattern would be best for this with low memory, high performance, and less overhead on developers to add/modify/use the utility. I liked your insight of using SQL